# How to fix random string starting with 'm_-' appended to classes after rendering the template in mustache

Tags: mustache

When adding styles classes to a template, after rendering the template in html the class name of each class get appended by a random string starting with 'm_-' which will not render the css

[screenshot of dev tool element section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aLq5.png)

i have tried to place the style in different parts in the html like in the body and and in the head, nothing works

**class in div before rendering**

```html
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
      .some-style{
         border : 1px solid black;
      }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="some-style"></div>
</body>
```

**class in div after rendering**

```html
<body>
 <div class="m_-818537353464745some-style"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show more of the template, including the script tag? There's no way to reproduce the problem with what you've shown. Are you sure mustache is doing that?

Comment: I'll give u more details in a while, thanks for making a comment, I thought no one will respond to this @wazz